# Adding Radio button in PDFfile using itex sharp version 1.4.6.0

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, radio-button, itext

I am writting this code to create radio button

```
 SizeF size = new SizeF(FieldBound.Width / 2, FieldBound.Height / 2);
                            PdfContentByte contentByte = PDFStamper.GetOverContent(item.PageNumber);
                            PdfAppearance[] radioButtonStates = new PdfAppearance[2];

                            radioButtonStates[0] = contentByte.CreateAppearance(FieldBound.Width, FieldBound.Height);
                            radioButtonStates[0].Circle(size.Width, size.Height, size.Width <= size.Height ? size.Width - 1 : size.Height - 1);
                            radioButtonStates[0].Stroke();

                            radioButtonStates[1] = contentByte.CreateAppearance(FieldBound.Width, FieldBound.Height);
                            radioButtonStates[1].Circle(size.Width, size.Height, size.Width <= size.Height ? size.Width - 1 : size.Height - 1);
                            radioButtonStates[1].Stroke();
                            radioButtonStates[1].Circle(size.Width, size.Height, size.Width <= size.Height ? (size.Width / 2) - 1 : (size.Height / 2) - 1);
                            radioButtonStates[1].FillStroke();

                            PdfFormField radioButton = PdfFormField.CreateRadioButton(PDFStamper.Writer, false);
                            radioButton.FieldName = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.GroupName) ? item.Name : item.GroupName);
                            radioButton.UserName = item.ToolTip;
                            radioButton.Rect = FieldBound;

                            radioButton.DefaultValueAsString = (item.Value.ToLower() == "true" ? "Yes" : "No");

                            if (item.ReadOnly)
                                radioButton.SetFieldFlags(BaseField.READ_ONLY);

                            if (item.Required)
                                radioButton.SetFieldFlags(BaseField.REQUIRED);

                            radioButton.Flags = PdfFormField.FLAGS_PRINT;

                            radioButton = SetRadioButtonAppearance(PDFStamper.Writer, FieldBound, radioButton, radioButtonStates, true);

                            PDFStamper.AddAnnotation(radioButton, item.PageNumber);
```

SetRadioButtonAppearance function is

```
   private PdfFormField SetRadioButtonAppearance(PdfWriter Writer,       iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Rectangle, PdfFormField RadioButtonField, PdfAppearance[] OnOff, bool On)
    {

        PdfFormField Field = PdfFormField.CreateRadioButton(Writer,true);
        Field.Flags = PdfFormField.FLAGS_PRINT;
        Field.SetWidget(Rectangle, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);

        if (On)
            Field.AppearanceState = "0";
        else
            Field.AppearanceState = "Off";

        Field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "0", OnOff[1]);
        Field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Off", OnOff[0]);
        Field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "On", OnOff[0]);

        Field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_DOWN, "0", OnOff[1]);
        Field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_DOWN, "Off", OnOff[0]);
        Field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_DOWN, "On", OnOff[0]);

        RadioButtonField.AddKid(Field);

        return RadioButtonField;

    }
```

yes radio button is created when i open pdf file it show this error
Editing a PDF will cause the PDF to no longer comply with PDF/A,are you sure you wish to cuntinue
NOTE:if PDF/A Complaince is required when the editiong is complete be sure to use save file-> save as other ->pdf/A
Can any body help what i am missing

Comment: The version of iTextSharp you are using dates from October 2006. Apart from the technical and legal issues that exist for that version, you should use software that is almost 9 years old. Please upgrade.

Comment: Just to further add to Bruno's comment, the PDF/A spec was barely a year old when when your version was released so to the best on my knowledge your version isn't even aware of it. According to the [release notes](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/205) PDF/A-1 was added in version 2.0.5.